# SharePoint 2016 cross farm services, Tagging is not working in consumer farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, mms, cross-farm

I have cross farm environment, SharePoint 2016 Nov PU 2016 level. We have UPA, MMS and Mysites in Publishing Farm. In consuming farm we have content web application. Now issue is Tagging in site collection news feed not working. I get the following message "Something went wrong The tagging service is currently unavailable. Please try again later."

- MMS service published and consumed in the content farm
  _ MMS service associated with the web application
- All the permission in place at both places.
- i cant find anything in uls logs.

One thing i noticed that if i have local MMS in consuming farm then tagging will work. but in this case if i click on the tag it tries pull from my profile and throws the following error "Sorry, something went wrong 
The query string "TermID" is missing or invalid. 
Technical Details"

So question, does tagging in site collection newsfeed required the local MMS and how can it pin with profile?